# Creating a cluster on private network

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, network

I'm currently running `geth`.

I have 4 nodes in my network and I'm willing to make them interact with each other.

On `host-01`, I've run:

```
geth --identity "Node1" --genesis /tmp/eth/genesis.json --rpc --rpcport \
    "8001" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir /tmp/eth/60/01/ --port "30301" \
    --nodiscover -ipcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" \
    -rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --autodag --networkid 4828 --nat \
    "any" console 2>> /tmp/eth/60/01.log
```

On `host-02`, I've copied the `genesis.json` file from `host-01`, and ran the same command, just changing the `--identity` argument.

Now I'm trying to make them talk to each other. I've obtained `host-01` enode:

```
admin.nodeInfo.enode
```

this gave me a string like:

```
"enode://6380bf79e7900309ac71612835f...@[::]:30301?discport=0"
```

Then, on `host-02`, I've run in the console:

```
admin.addPeer("enode://6380bf79e7900309ac71612835f...@[::]:30301?discport=0")
```

The result is `true`, but when I run:

```
admin.peers
```

it shows me an empty list.

What am I missing?

---

#### Edit

Additional info:
The hosts do see each other in the network (tested via `ping`) and the ports are up (tested via `telnet`), although the connection only keeps open for approximately 1 sec. Not sure if this is the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you could try adding the second node created from the first node that you created?

Comment: The [private network tutorial](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Setting-up-private-network-or-local-cluster) on the Geth github have got the ports as integers and not strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shame on me!

I've forgotten to change the network interface to reflect the actual IP address of the other node:

```
admin.addPeer("enode://6380bf79e7900309ac71612835f...@<HOST-02 IP HERE>:30301?discport=0")
```

Now works perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, but SE makes me wait 2 days before I can do so :/